# I'm trying to install Stardog on my linux system for some projects but curl isn't working and this is what happens with the documentation

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, vmware, curl

documentation:
https://docs.stardog.com/install-stardog/linux-installation

```
$ curl http://packages.stardog.com/stardog.gpg.pub | apt-key add
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
E: This command can only be used by root.
100  1760  100  1760    0     0    581      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   581
curl: (23) Failed writing body
aliza@ingestrom:~$ sudo curl http://packages.stardog.com/stardog.gpg.pub | apt-key add
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
E: This command can only be used by root.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1760  100  1760    0     0   1212      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  1212
curl: (23) Failed writing body
```

Comment: The "`E: This command can only be used by root.`" error lines show that you should `sudo apt-key add` instead of `apt-key add`. The other error "`curl: (23) Failed writing body`" is because `apt-key` has exited, and is no longer listening to the pipe, and `curl` noticed.

Comment: Even if I use the sudo command I get the same error message

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: [Edit] your question and show us how you "use the sudo command".

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> aliza@ingestrom:~$ sudo curl http://packages.stardog.com/stardog.gpg.pub | apt-key add
> ```

This runs `curl` as root. But `curl` only connects to a website (http://packages.stardog.com/stardog.gpg.pub), and outputs the content of that URL to standard output (stdout). That doesn't require any special permissions.

However, the pipe is a separator - you're running two commands; not one. First curl is executed, and stdout of curl is piped to stdin (standard input) of apt-key. The latter command needs root privileges.

The command that complains it has to be ran as root (`E: This command can only be used by root.`) is `apt-key`.

Change your command to

```
curl http://packages.stardog.com/stardog.gpg.pub | sudo apt-key add
```